# encrypting email with attachment in java

Tags: java, email, encryption, jakarta-mail

My project is to create simple mail client that handle basic operation like sending mail and read from inbox. However I want to make it more secure with some encryption. 
I know some about encryption using built-in javax.crypto. Also, i've successfully develop non-encryption mail client with java-mail library.
Oh yes, I also have check the [bouncy castle](http://bouncycastle.org/) and java-mail crypto.

Here is my code

```
public void send(...) {
// some config on mail props
// .....

Message message = ...;
message.setContent(multipart, "multipart");
MTPTransport smtpTransport = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtps");
smtpTransport.connect(host, username, password);

message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to, true));
smtpTransport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
....
}
```

At this point, im started to thinking wheter i have to encrypt "multipart" object, like :

```
message.setContent(AESEncrypt.encryptObject(multipart), "multipart");
```

and so on the reading mail method, there will be decrypt object.
Or what?

And here is part of my encryption method

```
public SealedObject encryptObject(Multipart multipart) {
SealedObject sealedObject = null;
Key secretKey = generateKey(startingKey);
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
sealedObject = new SealedObject(multipart, c);
return sealedObject;
}
```

I've ever read that we need serialized object first to be able to encrypt. Well, multipart isnt serialized object.
Am i got it wrong way? Do you have any better suggestion/reccomendation on which way is better? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a java.io.Serializable object, you just need the object to be "serialized", which in this case means turning it into a MIME format byte stream.

You can find Bouncy Castle examples as described [here](http://bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-2.WherecanIfindexamplesofhowtousetheAPIs?), and can download some other examples from [this page](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0764596330.html).  Your best bet is to start with one of these example programs.